# Convolution with kernel size larger than 5x5 in python-pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, convolution, python-imaging-library

I want to filter an image with a simple convolution kernel in python-pillow. However, to achieve optimal results, I need a 9x9 kernel. This is [not possible](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.Kernel) in pillow, at least when using `ImageFilter.Kernel` and the built-in `filter()` method, which are limited to 5x5 kernels.

Short of implementing my own convolution code, is there a way to filter/convolve an image with a kernel size larger than 5x5?

Comment: Can you show why it is not possible? - Just for completeness? Or some code trying it with an error?

Comment: Are you restricted to just using PIL?  Have you considered using OpenCV or `scipy`?

Comment: @User: It's stated explicitly in the documentation. Also, calling `filter()` with a larger kernel raises a "bad kernel size" ValueError.

Comment: @rayryeng No, I'd just prefer a solution using PIL because it's very simple and clean and otherwise exactly meets my needs. But I am currently looking into scipy.

Comment: I don't have experience in PIL but I'm surprised to see that you can't convolve with anything > 5 x 5.  In that case, if you're looking at `scipy`, have a look at `convolve` that's part of the `ndimage` package: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html .  You can load in an image using [`scipy.imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html), convolve, then convert to a PIL `Image` object with [`Image.fromArray`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)

Comment: BTW, let me know if the above works out for you... or if you decide to try it.  If it does work, I wouldn't mind writing a formal answer!

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, that works perfectly! Converting it back to a PIL image was only academic for my purposes because I can just use the scipy array for my application, but it's nice to know that this is possible in principle. Thank you!

Comment: @jpfender - Cool! Let me write an answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite surprised to see that PIL doesn't have support beyond 5 x 5 kernels.  As such, it may be prudent to look at other Python packages, such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) or [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org/)... for the interest of saving time, let's use `scipy`.  OpenCV is a pain to configure even though it's quite powerful.

I would recommend using `scipy` to load in your image with [`imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) from the `ndimage` package, convolve the image with your kernel, then convert to a PIL image when you're done.  Use [`convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) from the `ndimage` package, then convert back to a PIL image by [`Image.fromArray`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray). It does have support to convert a `numpy.ndarray` (which is what is loaded in when you use `scipy.ndimage.imread`), which is great.

Something like this, assuming a 9 x 9 averaging filter:

```
# Import relevant packages
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image

# Read in image - change filename to whatever you want
img = ndimage.imread('image.jpg')

# Create kernel
ker = (1/81.0)*np.ones((9,9))

# Convolve
out = ndimage.convolve(img, ker)

# Convert back to PIL image
out = Image.fromArray(out, 'RGB')
```

Answer (score 2):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) is another option, if you're not tied to pillow, numpy or scipy. It's quite a bit faster and needs a lot less memory, especially for larger images. It'll beat opencv too, [at least on some benchmarks](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use).

I tried on this laptop:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image

img = ndimage.imread(sys.argv[1])
ker = (1 / 81.0) * np.ones((9, 9))
out = ndimage.convolve(img, ker)
out = Image.fromarray(out)
out.save(sys.argv[2])
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./try257.py ~/pics/wtc-mono.jpg x.jpg
300352:22.47
```

So a 10k x 10k pixel mono jpg on a 2015 i5 laptop takes about 22 seconds and needs a peak of 300mb of memory.

In pyvips it's:

```
import sys
import pyvips

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access="sequential")
size = 9
kernel = size * [size * [1.0 / (size * size)]]
im = im.conv(kernel)
im.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./try258.py ~/pics/wtc-mono.jpg x.jpg
44336:4.76
```

About 5 seconds and 45mb of memory.

That's a float convolution. You can swap it to int precision like this:

```
im = im.conv(kernel, precision="integer")
```

And I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./try258.py ~/pics/wtc-mono.jpg x.jpg
44888:1.79
```

1.8 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this newer answer!

Comment: Thanks! Though the libvips Python binding has been rewritten since. I've updated it to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! Curious. Did you compare with scikit-image? Curious on what the benchmarks are with that.

Comment: Yes that's right. I don't see it in the benchmarks, but I do like how this library was developed

Comment: OK, added scikit-image. It's 29x slower than pyvips on that test on my machine. Perhaps I made some horrible error :(

Comment: No I think that's right.  I forgot that scikit-image doesn't have general convolution functions.  They don't want to replace scipy but complement it.  We'll leave it at that.